# Build a sequence from a iter function

Tags: ocaml

I want to build a sequence from an iter function. I didn't really get how that works:

```
 (('a ‑> unit) ‑> unit) ‑> 'a t
```

Can any one explain how does this work please? I think I should just pass an iter to `from_fun` and inside the function declare the function `f` that should take a parameter. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know about sequences, but your second branch is dead code: if `iter f ()` has type `unit`, the only possible match for its value is `()` in the first branch.

Comment: How you define sequence? How you define `iter` function? Why every time when you ask a question, I feel guilty for not reading your previous posts?

Comment: actually i am trying to replace all enum functions by sequence functions, so i am using almost same definitions am sorry if my posts are not so clear am totaly new in ocaml. in what concerns iter and f that was my question "Can any one explain how does this work please? " so i know that f is a function that takes an element 'a and returns unit and iter takes f and returns unit, but am confused about what do these functions-_-

Comment: Mmmh, you just destroyed your question by editing it so the comments make no sense at all, now.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators of type `type 'a iter = ('a -> unit) -> unit` are internal iterators: when used they iter on the whole underlying sequence and only give back control to the caller at the end of the sequence. Contrarily, the sequence type is an external iterator that gives back control to the caller after each step. It is easy to get from an external iterator to an internal iterator with

```
let rec to_iter seq f = match seq () with
| Nil -> ()
| Cons(x, seq) -> f x; to_iter seq f
```

because it means giving up on control that you have. The other direction cannot work as nicely since there is no way to synchronize the iterations of iter with the steps of the sequence. The only solution is then to store the whole collection being iterated upon then transform it to a sequence, essentially doing `iter |> to_list |> List.to_seq`.

Comment: but just with iterators definition we should have a data structure on which iterate so how can we use these type of iterators if we don't have a data structure on which iterate(because in these case wa wanna create a sequence using an iterator) that's what confusing??

Comment: The information about the underlying data structure is hidden away in the innards of the iterator closure and cannot be recovered from the outside world. Basically, the only thing that you can do with an iterator is to iterate on the whole structure in a one go. This is enough in many case. For instance, to sum all the elements of an `int` iterator: `let sum iter = let ref s = 0 in iter (fun x -> s:= !s + x) ; !s`.

Comment: You can raise an exception during iter (from the called function), thus regaining control.

Comment: True, you can interrupt the iteration with an exception, but you cannot restart it; so the amount of control that you struggle back with exception is limited.